# What is the current capacity of this cable?

Tags: wire

[image]

This is a 8 wire 0.5mm2 cable (insulator is PVC), there's 17 strings of copper in each wire.

I couldn't find the current capacity of this specific wire on their website but their 1.5mm2 x 8 cables are capable of handling 27A when distance is about 10 meter (reduces to 5A when distance is 150 meter).

I'm going to pass a maximum of 7-8A through two of this wires (other wires gonna carry about 1A) and the distance is about 1.5-2 meter.

Can this wire handle 8 amperes of current?

```
wires current:
1. LEDs       12V  30W  2.5A
2. Waterpump 220V  40W ~200mA
3. Airpump   220V  20W ~100mA
4. Heater    220V 300W  1.5A
5. MCU*        5V ----  500mA

*there's some relays connected to MCU that's why it's using 500mA.
and two wires gonna be 220V INPUT which gonna carry ~5A in total.
```

Comment: Add a hyperlink to the website.

Comment: @Andyaka the website language is in Persian, i don't think that can help anyone...

Comment: Just for your information: The cross sectional area of the copper is not the only thing to be taken into the account. Even a thick cable can get overheated if the dissipated heat cannot go away; for ex. the cable is assembled inside a thermal insulation of a wall. For this reason electricity installations are tightly regulated and the allowed cable types are listed.

Comment: @user287001 the cable gonna be in room temperature in the air...

Comment: Its hard to say man, my gut feeling says 5-6 amps for 10m .. You could perform an outdoors test with 16 amps. I would just buy some new wires I knew the specifications of. Good luck, and dont burn down a building! ... So much paperwork

Comment: @Sorenp thanks man, that's what i'm worried about. "burning the house down"! lol

Comment: Then calculate the total cross section area of the copper in one wire in square millimeters. Then we can say something useful. The thickness 0,5mm is a little poor information.

Comment: @user287001 it's 0.5mm2, i'll edit the question right now...

Comment: Useful link: https://www.axon-cable.com/en/06_customerArea/03_toolbox/04_intensity/index.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the resistance is 300% of the resistance of 1.5 mm^2 wire and the thermal cooling area is only 57%, you can keep it cool enough if one wire has max 2 amperes RMS continuously in free air. Four wires in parallel can handle 8 A.

But that's not all! How long is your cable? Do the fuses trip in case of a short circuit soon enough (=before there's a fire)? There's length limitations is regulations also for that reason. What wires are before your cable affects too!

Get local pro help to check your distribution system!

Comment: the length is 2 meter, you mean each wire can only handle 2A otherwise it'll get hot?

Comment: Yes, that I mean. I wrote the 2A because it allows also having the cable in a protective duct. If you can be sure it's laying on a floor or wall uncovered, you can rise the current to 2,8A per a wire.

Comment: Thanks, i used [This](https://www.axon-cable.com/en/06_customerArea/03_toolbox/04_intensity/index.aspx) website calculator and it says 5.5A...

Comment: I used North European tables. They are very conservative. Here the current could be 5A if the cable was sunken inside the ground. Hanging in free air the max current is 3,8A.. You should notice that I made an assumption of the cooling area.